# Copying single Excel cell value into Outlook body

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to understand how to copy a single excel cell value into outlook body. Thus far, I have only been able to find posts using cell ranges. Thank you.

Comment: A single cell is a range...

Answer (score 0):

You should use this line to get the A2 cell value for example :

```
Sheets("mySheet").Range("A2").Value
```

Let me know for more informations.